# Button element click event to toggleClass doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I have a on/off button that is featured [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-on-off-button/)

I have all the elements in place and im expecting the button class `.on` to initiate when pressed.

Only it wont work no matter what i try.

i added the exact code in jsFiddle, it works there, but not on my page.

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhBEy/1/)
- [My page](http://www.tranceil.fm/player2)

I'm adding the HTML inside jquery:

```
'<section>'+
        '<button id="button" href="#">&#xF011;</button>'+
    '<span>'+
    '</span>'+
'</section>'+
```

I'm guessing its a conflict between CSS elements but i cant pinpoint the problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('on');
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx Enve, i never thought it would be that simple and easily overlooked, ill accept once the 9 minuetes limit is passed.

Answer (score 3):

In jsFiddle you are correctly binding the event within `$(document).ready()`, while in your own page you are not. So in jsFiddle, the event is correctly bound to the `button` element only after the DOM is ready, while in your own page the event fails to bind since the element does not exist yet at that stage.

Comment: Thanx m8, but i have to accept Enve's answer. he was first :) thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I can see this in your page's HTML:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      $('#player').metroPlayer();
   });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#button').on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('on');
   });
</script>
```

You need to place your `on()` function **inside** the `$(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#button').click(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('on');
      });
    });
```